# How to execute cmd Commands using DOS, and change to current path to a specific path?

Tags: php, cmd

I want to execute cmd commands using PHP, but I don';t want to execute it on the root path, rather for example on this path `c:/dir1/dir2` in addition to that I want to set parameters to the executing command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chdir('c:\dir1\dir2');
$result = `cmdname arg1 arg2 ...`;
```